# UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to submit a remote job in mapreduce, but I get the error [1].
I even have set in hdfs-site.xml in the remote hadoop the content [2], and changed permissions [3], but the problem remains.

The client is xeon, and the superuser is xubuntu.

How I add a remote user permission to submit in mapreduce? How I set a group for xeon?

[1]

```
2015-04-23 05:57:35,648 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user xeon
```

[2]

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.web.ugi</name>
    <value>xeon,webuser,webgroup</value>
</property>
```

[3]

```
2041  hdfs dfs -chown -R xeon:supergroup /user/xeon
2045  hdfs dfs -chown -R xeon:supergroup /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/xeon/
2039  hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /user/xeon
2053  hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/xeon
```

​

### --

Answer (score 0):

Add users & groups on RM host.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! would you please enhance your answer?